# How to allow AD users the ability to change password if expired?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, active-directory

If you have an application that is being authenticated with Active Directory using Forms Authentication in MVC, how can you allow the user to change his password after it expires?

From what I am observing, if a user's password has expired, Membership provider will simply refuse to let you authenticate, thus not allowing the user to access the page. However, if I modify the page, to allow the user to go to it, and enter a user name, old password, and new password, it still seems to not work, just returning 'false' from the change password function.

Any insight or solutions on this?

Comment: Since your user isn't authenticated, does your application have enough permissions to write to Active Directory?

Answer (score 0):

> Any insight or solutions on this?

Insight refering to scripts. if yes so please have a look at these links

http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/08/17/how-to-change-a-user-s-active-directory-password-with-powershell.aspx

http://community.spiceworks.com/scripts/show/1889-reset-ad-user-password

Moreover there are many self rest solution. Please update so that a name would be explained to you

Thanks.